# List<Collision2D> заполняется неправильно и очищается сам по себе

Tags: c#, unity3d

(это описание тестирования проблемы, задаю вопрос с разных форумов Q&A: cyberforum и stackoverflow. [Вопрос на киберфоруме (с чего все началось).](https://www.cyberforum.ru/unity/thread2769328.html))

Создаете 3 объекта: button, на котором будет висеть скрипт объявления объекта (wirePref):

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RectTransform wirePref;
    public async void V()
    {
        RectTransform wire = Instantiate(wirePref, new Vector2(), Quaternion.identity, transform);
        wire.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(282.48f, 83.6f);
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        V1(wire);
        await Task.Delay(3000);
    }
    public void V1(RectTransform wire)
    {
        List<Collision2D> cols = wire.GetComponent<ScriptCTW>().collisions;
        cols.ForEach(col => print(col.collider.name));
        wire.GetComponent<ScriptCTW>().basesCollision.ForEach(col => print(col.name));
    }
}
```

и создаем еще 2 объекта под button (button - родитель для этих 2 объектов) с твердым телом и коллайдером:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Они должны располагаться так, чтобы объект

```
public RectTransform wirePref;
```

, создавшись, соединял эти 2 объекта и касался их. На созданном объекте должны быть такие же твердое тело (kinematic), коллайдер и его скрипт:

```
public class ScriptCTW : MonoBehaviour
{
public List<Transform> basesCollision = new List<Transform>();
public List<Collision2D> collisions = new List<Collision2D>();
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.CompareTag("Base"))
        {
            basesCollision.Add(collision.transform);
            collisions.Add(collision);
        }
    }
}
```

Итак, нажимаем на button, запускается функция V

```
public async void V()
```

.
Все. Функция V1 выведет на экран сначала имя последнего объекта 2 раза (так не должно быть)

```
cols.ForEach(col => print(col.collider.name))
```

, а затем имена двух объектов (это правильно)

```
wire.GetComponent<ScriptCTW>().basesCollision.ForEach(col => print(col.name));
```

Общая итоговая картина:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрел, что происходит в отладке, когда запускается метод OnCollisionEnter2D. Когда то collisions пустой, когда то нет, но в любом случае при распаковке collisions в методе V1

```
cols.ForEach(col => print(col.collider.name));
```

всегда выводит только имя того объекта, с которым столкнулся wirePref в последний раз, и выводит столько раз, сколько объектов, с которыми wirePref столкнулся (пример выше).

Comment: `Test`, `V`, `V1`, `ScriptCTW`... **WildForestNamingConvention** 

Comment: Лучше опишите решаемую вами задачу, ощущение, что вы с этими коллайдами, небрежно надеваете штаны через голову.

Comment: полная задача - это генерация карты. я вам как можно понятнее дал пример проблемы, чтобы вы сделали так же у себя, как я, а потом уже сказали в чем причина этого бага (collisions заполняется неправильно). не обращайте внимание на имена классов. помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: V - это некоторый кусок кода из метода Generation. Test - ScriptMapGeneration. V1 - BaseAlignment. ScriptCTW - ScriptConstructionTargetWire. Object - Base. но, я думаю, понятнее не станет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только что решил проблему. Когда запускается OnCollisionEnter2D, переменная collision просто присваивает себе новое значение. Я добавлял эту переменную в список, а так как это класс, то в списке эта переменная тоже заменит значение.
Сделал класс, хранящий в себе те свойства Collision2D, которые мне нужны.
Вопрос закрыт.